# Trigger not creating in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to write a trigger for my database in mySQL yet when I run the query and then run SHOW TRIGGERS nothing is showing. I believe my syntax is correct and am not running into any errors when running the query. The query is below, any ideas why this is happening?

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_violation_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON violation
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE listing
SET Listing_True_False = "true"
WHERE Listing_ID = new.Listing_ID;
```

Comment: I could not find any syntax error in it and you claim you did not run into any error. Does `select trigger_name from information_schema.triggers ;` or `show create trigger after_violation_insert;` return anything ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34a87a77d020431f5486f77c2d4442cf are you certain you are in the db where you created the trigger